# Missing ( in citep

Tags: bibtex

I have a citation of an accessed website, but when I cite it together with multiple papers, the parenthesis is missing.
[image]
Does anybody know How I can fix this?

```
@article{weisstein2000levenberg,
  title={Levenberg-Marquardt Method},
  author={Weisstein, Eric W},
  journal={https://mathworld. wolfram. com/},
  year={2000 (accessed November 10, 2020)},
  publisher={Wolfram Research, Inc.}
}
```

Comment: Please post some compilable code.

Answer (score 1):

I will give you an example using `biblatex`. In this scenario, in your reference, the problem lies in the field `year`, which should be numeric.

The "accesed ..." note must appear in the References, not in the text.

Or use the `url` and `urldate`(format YYYY-MM-DD) fields in which case you get, without further intervention from your part,  the text "Retrieved on October 10, 2020, from https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ "  printed at the end.

Or use the field `note`, in which case you will get what you wrote inside square brackets, like `[my text]`.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage[style=apa,
    backend=biber,
    natbib=true,
    language=american]
    {biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname45.bib}
    
@article{weisstein2000levenberg,
    title={Levenberg-Marquardt Method},
    author={Weisstein, Eric W},
    url={https://mathworld.wolfram.com/},
    urldate  = {2020-10-10},
    year=2000,
    publisher={Wolfram Research, Inc.},
}

@article{yoon,
    author       = {Yoon, Myeong S. and Ryu, Dowook and Kim, Jeongryul and Ahn,
        Kyo Han},
    title        = {Palladium pincer complexes with reduced bond angle strain:
        efficient catalysts for the {Heck} reaction},
    journaltitle = {Organometallics},
    date         = 2006,
    volume       = 25,
    number       = 10,
    pages        = {2409-2411},
    indextitle   = {Palladium pincer complexes},    
}
    
@book{worman,
    author       = {Worman, Nancy},
    title        = {The Cast of Character},
    date         = 2002,
    publisher    = {University of Texas Press},
    location     = {Austin},
    langid       = {english},
}   

@article{Carlson2011, 
    author = {Carlson, Nicholas},
    booktitle = {Businessinsider.com},
    title = {{How Many Users Does Twitter REALLY Have?}},
    note = {Available online at \url{www.businessinsider.com/chart-of-the-day-how-many-users-does-twitter-really-have-2011-31/3}},
    year = {2011},
}

\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname45.bib}

\begin{document}    

    It behave like Gauss--Newton and  closer to gradient descent 
(\cite{weisstein2000levenberg}; \cite{worman}; \cite{yoon} and \cite{Carlson2011}).

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output]